# NameError: name '__builtin__' is not defined while installing SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've installed Python 2.7.2 on my Windows XP computer.

I recently installed SQLAlchemy 0.7.1 using 'python setup.py install'. During the installation, I got the following error messages:

```
byte-compiling C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py to visitors.pyc
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy\\sql\\visitors.py', 66, 34, 'class Visitable(object, metaclass=VisitableType):\n'))
```

When I try to `import sqlalchemy`, I get the following stack trace:

```
>>> import sqlalchemy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  from sqlalchemy.sql import (
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import (
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py", line 32, in <module>
from sqlalchemy import util, exc
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from .compat import callable, cmp, reduce, defaultdict, py25_dict, \
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 93, in <module>
callable = __builtin__.callable
NameError: name '__builtin__' is not defined
```

Other scripts work fine and all the functions in `__builtin__` seem to be available.

I can't find any examples of similar problems on Google or in the SQLAlchemy documentation.

What's wrong?

**UPDATE**:

Uncommenting `import __builtin__` in compat.py removed the first problem. Now I seem to have problems with visitors.py:

```
>>> import sqlalchemy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from sqlalchemy.sql import (
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import (
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py", line 35, in <module>
from sqlalchemy.sql.visitors import Visitable, cloned_traverse
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 66
class Visitable(object, metaclass=VisitableType):
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: does the installed `compat.py` have  `import __builtin__` in it? as the source version does.

Comment: Yeah, it was commented out. Now I'm getting a brand new error (see above)...

Comment: so it seems that the code was transformed for python 3, and that version will not work with python 2.7.2, but i have no clue as to why `python setup.py install` would do that as it should only do so when ran by python 3. so what is the version of python that ran the `setup.py`?

Comment: The executable claims to be 2.7.2. I suspected the same thing, but can't find any way to prove anything untoward happened. I don't even have a Python 3 interpreter installed (although I used to have it).

I guess I'll try reinstalling Python.

Comment: I re-installed Python and removed left-over directories from both installations (3 and 2). I still get the first error and the same compilation syntax errors from visitors.py.

Answer (score 0):

Problem partially solved: everything started working when I rolled back to SQLAlchemy 0.6.8. An issue with 0.7.1 + Windows/2.6?